# Validate input for nested list in python

Tags: python-3.x, nested-lists

newbie for python here.

i'm trying to validate if user input is empty for a nested list to store (x y coordinate). If user did not input anything, codes should be displaying a message e.g. "No input" and will loop back prompting the user to input.

Had been searching everywhere on validate empty nested list, or validate empty input but i just can't put the knowledge together. An example of the code is display below:

```
add = "y"
xy = []

#-------------------------------------
def count_list(l):
    count = 0
    for e in l:
        if isinstance(e, list):
            count = count + 1 + count_list(e)
    return count
#--------------------------------------

while (add == "y"):

    xy.append([(input("Input x value: ")), (input("Input y value: "))])

    add = input("Additional (x, y)? [y/n] ")

qty = (count_list(xy))

print ("(x, y) coordinate(s) inserted:- " + str(xy))

print ("No. of coordinate(s) inserted:- " + str(qty))
```

---

**Output**

[image]

---

Had been cracking my brain for this. Notice 2nd nested list is empty. Am trying to find out how stop the code to proceed but instead prompting the user with a msg "no input". The position of the empty nested list should not be added into the list.

Also have no idea why my count_list function also include counting in an empty nested list. T_T

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do to avoid counting an empty input is `continue` when you see that the input is empty.

```
while (add == "y"):
    x_val = input("Input x value: ")
    y_val = input("Input y value: ")
    # not x_val checks if the string is an empty string
    if not x_val or not y_val:
        print("Error: No input. Try again.")
        continue

    xy.append([(x_val), (y_val)])

    add = input("Additional (x, y)? [y/n] ")
```

Output:

```
Input x value: 1
Input y value: 2
Additional (x, y)? [y/n] y
Input x value:
Input y value:
Error: No input. Try again.
Input x value: 5
Input y value: 6
Additional (x, y)? [y/n] n
(x, y) coordinate(s) inserted:- [['1', '2'], ['5', '6']]
No. of coordinate(s) inserted:- 2
```

Comment: What the... was spending half a day on this and you nailed it ! Thanks a lot.